# How to access $files from child scope with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive which I can use like this:

```
<input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
```

This works just fine in the main scope, but when I try to use it within a **repeater and then inside include:**

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
    <div ng-include="tab.url"></div>
</div>
```

**tab.url:**

```
<input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
```

It stops working, no data is sent to the scope.

**ngFileSelect directive:**

```
app.directive("ngFileSelect", function () {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, el) {
            el.bind("change", function (e) {
                for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
                    $scope.file = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[i];
                     $scope.getFile();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In my **controller** i have:

```
$scope.getFile = function() {
    fileReader.readAsDataUrl($scope.file, $scope)
        .then(function(result) {
            $scope.images.push(result);
        });
};
```

How can I access the files selected inside the included file in a tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$scope.getFile = function() {
    var currentScope = this; //access the file from current scope instead of from $scope which is always your controller's scope

    fileReader.readAsDataUrl(currentScope.file, currentScope)
        .then(function(result) {
            currentScope.images.push(result);
        });
};
```

The reason is scope inheritance, `ng-repeat` and `ng-include` create child scopes. The selected file is assigned to a **child scope**:

```
$scope.file = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[i];
```

And then call:

```
$scope.getFile(); //this is inherited from parent scope (controller)
```

In the `getFile` function, you're accessing `$scope.file` (your controller's scope) that does not have the `file` assigned.